# UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark removes as UITableView moves up?

Tags: uitableview

I do check in `didSelectRow` Method, but as I move up the table, it removes the check
I think its creating new Cell

How can I use unique cell so that it would not replace the checked cell to unchecked.

```
- (void)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"MY INDEX PATH IS %@", indexPath);

    NSString *email = [allEmails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (tableAlert.type == SBTableAlertTypeMultipleSelct) {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableAlert.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone){
             [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
             [selectedEmail addObject:email];
        }

        else{
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
            [selectedEmail removeObject:email];

        }

       [tableAlert.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
 }

     NSLog(@"Final Array is %@", selectedEmail);
 }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell;

    // NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];


if (tableAlert.view.tag == 0 || tableAlert.view.tag == 1) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
} else {
    // Note: SBTableAlertCell
    cell = [[SBTableAlertCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
}

//[cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", indexPath.section]];

NSString *email = [allEmails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", email];


UIFont *myFont = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 14.0 ];
cell.textLabel.font  = myFont;

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already storing the selected emails in *selectedEmail* array, you can make use of it in the *cellForRowAtIndexPath* method to display the checkmark:

```
NSString *email = [allEmails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", email];
if ([selectedEmail indexOfObject:email] != NSNotFound) {
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
}
else {
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}
```

In this way, even if the cell is reused, there will not be any issue.